# Axios, promesa devuelve Promise <pending> o undefined

Tags: nodejs, promesas

Estaba intentando que esa funcion llamara a una API y despues me regresara algo pero cuando intento hacer el return me regresa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todo esto si lo imprimer bien como se puede ver en la parte de arriba pero cuando intento retornarlo me sale undefined o tambien me puede salir Promise.

Si alguien me puede ayudar porfavor.

```
const getUsers = ( email , password) => {
    let data = "None";
    axios.post( authUrl, authData, authConf )
        .then( response => {
            const token = response.data.access_token;
            const queryData = {
                "commands":"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = \'" + email + "\' AND PASSWORD = \'" + password + "\';",
                "limit":10,
                "separator":";",
                "stop_on_error":"no"
            }
            const queryConf = {
                headers: {
                    "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "csontent-Type": 'application/json',
                    "x-deployment-id": credentials.instance_administration_api.deployment_id
                }
            }
            axios.post( queryUrl, queryData, queryConf )
                .then( response => {
                    //Get query results
                    const getDataUrl = `${queryUrl}/${response.data.id}`;
                    axios.get( getDataUrl, queryConf )
                        .then( responde => {
                            data = responde.data.results[0].rows; 
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        } );
                } );
        } )
}
```

Comment: porque 2 lineas en la consola si solo tienes un console.log? se ejecuta 2 veces la funcion ?

Comment: un console.log se ejecuta adentro de las funciones y otra es del return data que por fuera de la funcion se manda llamar

Comment: pues ahi se supone te está mostrando los datos que retornó la API... puedes especificar mejor cual es entonces el problema? en la pregunta dices que esperas que te regresara "algo" pero que te regresa eso que pusiste... que es ese "algo" que esperabas que te regresara? donde está entonces el error?

Comment: Ese algo espero que sea el objeto no solo que lo muestre, quiero que me lo regrese que es en el primer linea de terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entonces lo que debes hacer es retornar la promesa en todos lados hasta que sea resuelta por completo

```
const getUsers = ( email , password) => {
    let data = "None";
    return axios.post( authUrl, authData, authConf )
        .then( response => {
            const token = response.data.access_token;
            const queryData = {
                "commands":"SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = \'" + email + "\' AND PASSWORD = \'" + password + "\';",
                "limit":10,
                "separator":";",
                "stop_on_error":"no"
            }
            const queryConf = {
                headers: {
                    "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                    "csontent-Type": 'application/json',
                    "x-deployment-id": credentials.instance_administration_api.deployment_id
                }
            }
            return axios.post( queryUrl, queryData, queryConf )
                .then( response => {
                    //Get query results
                    const getDataUrl = `${queryUrl}/${response.data.id}`;
                    return axios.get( getDataUrl, queryConf )
                        .then( responde => {
                            data = responde.data.results[0].rows; 
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        } );
                } );
        } )
}
```

Y la debes usar como `getUsers(email,pass).then(data => console.log(data))`